# How can i add CSS styling to a asp.net listview?

Tags: css, asp.net

I know that it's not possible to directly add css styles to a listview but is there any way round this? I'm trying to create a news page where each news block is contained within a box essentially. 
Here is my listview code

```
    <div>

    <asp:ListView  ID="lvNews" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlNewsDataSource">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" CssClass="subtitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="news_image" Width="300px" Height="250px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Imageurl") %>'/>
            <br/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="NewsLabel" CssClass="bodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("News") %>' />
            <br />
            <br/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlNewsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sqlMUConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Title], [News], [Imageurl] FROM [News]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
```

And the css style that Im trying to apply

```
    /*News Page*/
.newsBox {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the items in your `ItemTemplate` with a div of that class.

Like this:

```
<asp:ListView  ID="lvNews" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlNewsDataSource">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="newsBox">
            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" CssClass="subtitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="news_image" Width="300px" Height="250px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Imageurl") %>'/>
            <br/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="NewsLabel" CssClass="bodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("News") %>' />
            <br />
            <br/>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @zgood . This is exactly what I was looking for. Dont know why I didn't try that myself...

Comment: No problem. If you would prefer to use Web Form controls you can replace the `div` with a `<asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="newsBox">` because a `<asp:Panel>` renders out as a `div`. You can also add `runat="server"` to the `div` if you need to access in code-behind.